# Shortcut to send messages in Outlook 2011 for Mac

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2011

I know there is a shortcut Cmd+Enter to send open message in Outlook 2011 for Mac. However, this conflicts with Lion's default shortcut Cmd+Enter, which makes any window full-screen.

How do I change this behavior, preferably a different shortcut for sending messages in Outlook.

Thanks.

Comment: There's no default shortcut to make any window fullscreen. Are you running MegaZoomer or a similar utility?

Comment: Oh right. I forgot to remove the megazoomer plugin when I upgraded from SL to Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this turned out to be an issue with MegaZoomer, I will still answer the question in case anyone else is interested.

You can reassign any keyboard shortcut for any application running on OS X from the System Preferences.

see: http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/2394-how-to-reassign-key-combinations-in-outlook-2011-for-mac/

Answer (score 0):

**Hotkey to send outlook message on a mac:**

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

To send a message in Outlook on a mac we can use the keyboard shortcut or hotkey Command and press enter.